# Secured HL7 Transport in WS02 ESB?

Tags: ssl, wso2, esb, hl7

My group is evaluating HL7 Proxying and came across WS02 ESB.  I have successfully configured an HL7 Proxy that seems to work well.  Now my task is to secure the listening point with SSL (TLS specifically).  This seems like something that the ESB should be able to handle.  It can do HTTPS, Secured Web Services, etc.  However, there doesn't seem to be a way to enable this with a simple check box for HL7 Proxying, nor am I finding any documentation on how to enable it manually.

Is it even possible to do secured HL7 Proxying within WS02 ESB?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems WSO2 is using [HAPI client](http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/) for HL7 implementation and when I go through the code it seems TLS is disabled by default. Refer https://github.com/wso2/carbon-mediation/blob/master/components/business-adaptors/hl7/org.wso2.carbon.business.messaging.hl7.transport/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/business/messaging/hl7/transport/HL7TransportListener.java#L78