# Why secured HL7 Transport in WSO2 EI is disabled?

Tags: wso2, hapi, hl7-v2, wso2-esb

I would like to use a secure connection for exchanging hl7 messages with WSO2 EI.

Refers to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38719187/2473158) my doubt is why this option is disabled in the code of the HL7TransportListener since hl7 connections carry very sensitive data.

Thanks in advance